# Combining Overline in Obj C

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, nsmutablestring

This problem should be simple. I've done quite a bit of searching and found that the 'combining overline' unicode is /u0305.

Here's the task, I want a series of numbers to be covered with ONE overline. I've seen it on a dozen wiki pages. I can do this in Word and elsewhere, but not encoding, for some reason. But in iOS with a simple text field, with the variety of fonts I've tried, I can't seem to get xCode to display a SINGLE OVERLINE over a series of characters.

Example of code:

```
 NSString *numbers = @"12134";
 NSMutableString *numbersM = [numbers mutableCopy];
 for (int i = 0; i < [numbers length]; i++)
 {
      [numbersM insertString:@"\u0305" atIndex:(2*i+1)];
 }

 //So now numbersM includes all the overline codes. 
 [displayTest setText:numbersM];
```

The result is NOT like this (which I copied from elsewhere)

1̅2̅3̅4̅

But instead it reads like more like this (the overlines won't combine!) 
 1̅
 2̅

Comment: The way this looks in the end depends _entirely_ on the font. Try different fonts until you find one where the lines connect.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I've tried quite a few... any recommendations?

Comment: Sorry, no, it's not a construct I've tried to make before.

Comment: I think SO uses Arial for the body of posts; you might try that.